# I - T not isomorphism in non-Banach normed spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

So I know that if $T : X \to X$ is a bounded operator with $X$ a Banach space and that $\|T\| < 1$, then $I - T$ is an isomorphism. Is this true in general normed spaces?

Comment: The condition $\|T\|<1$ looks like it's designed to obtain a contraction mapping and exploit completeness of $X$. If that's the case in the proof of the fact you mentioned then the answer, I think, would probably be "no".

Comment: No, completeness is important. If we denote the completion of $X$ with $\tilde{X}$ and the extension of $T$ with $\tilde{T}$, it need not be the case that $(\tilde{I} - \tilde{T})^{-1}(X) \subset X$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks! You would not happen to have an explicit counterexample would you?

Comment: Sure. Let $X$ be the space of sequences with only finitely many nonzero terms. Endow it with your favourite $\ell^p$-norm. Let $T(e_k) = \frac{1}{2} e_{k+1}$. Then $(I-T)^{-1}(e_1)$ has infinitely many nonzero terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, let $X$ be the polynomials with the norm
$$ \|f\| = \sup_{x \in [0,1/2]} |f(x)|$$
and $$T(f)(x) = \int_0^x f(t)\; dt$$
It is easy to see that $\|T\| \le 1/2$.  But $I-T$ is not an isomorphism, 
e.g. there is no $f$ such that $f - Tf = 1$ (as you see by differentiating the
equation $f(x) - \int_0^x f(t)\; dt = 1$, leading to a differential equation initial value problem whose solution is not a polynomial).